# How to Pull Relative Click Data in GTM with a Custom JavaScript Variable

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I want to pull header of a part of my landing page by tag manager, when someone click on read more button .
so
I use this tutorial: https://measureschool.com/relative-click-variable/
but it couldn't work

then, I use this tutorial: https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/css-selector-guide-google-tag-manager/

but it couldn't work

how can I fetch this header or something like that by custom javaScript in tag manager?

[pictures of tag manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lyOfB.jpg)

Comment: Tutorials are not the things that don't work. Show your code. And show the actual HTML including the CTA and the header that you want to capture. Specify exactly what you need on what click. It's a trivial one-liner, we'll write it for you.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.